Robot_localization - navsat_transform_node: "Will not remove offset of navsat device from robot's origin" - SOLVED: tf timestamps were too far in time
OS: Ubuntu 22.04
ROS Distribution: ROS 2 Humble
robot_localization Package Version: 3.5.3

Description of the issue
Sensor inputs:

GNSS receiver: publishes NavSatFix on topic /ublox_gps_node/fix

Running nodes:

my_odom_node:

publishes odometry{parent: "odom", child: "aft_mapped"} on topic /aft_mapped_to_init
publishes transform{odom -> aft_mapped} on topic /tf


navsat_transform_node: (configuration given below)
ekf_node: (configuration given below)

Launch configuration:
    # Grabs GNSS fix (and /odometry/global for redundancy) and publishes on /odometry/gps --> [frame_id = map | no child]
    gnss_fix_to_odometry_node = Node(
          package="robot_localization",
          executable="navsat_transform_node",
          name="navsat_transform",
          output="screen",
          parameters=[rl_params_file, {"use_sim_time": False}],
          remappings=[
              ("odometry/filtered", "odometry/global"), # IN
              ("gps/fix", "/ublox_gps_node/fix"),           # IN

              ("odometry/gps", "odometry/gps"),         # OUT
          ],
      )

    local_global_odometry_EKF_node = Node(
        package="robot_localization",
        executable="ekf_node",
        name="ekf_filter_node_map",
        parameters=[rl_params_file, {"use_sim_time": False}],
        remappings=[("odometry/filtered", "odometry/global")],
    )

Output
When starting everything, I get this error message:

[navsat_transform_node-5] [ERROR] [1726738973.601752606] [navsat_transform]:
Could not obtain map -> aft_mapped transform. Will not remove offset of navsat device from robot's origin

Expected behavior
From what I understand, navsat_transform_node is expecting a map -> aft_mapped tf, but this transform is actually provided in two parts:

odom -> aft_mapped (given by my_odom_node)
map -> odom (given by ekf_filter_node_map)

So is it a bug that navsat_transform_node complains about not having "map -> aft_mapped"?
More information about the setup:
robot_localization configuration (rl_params_file):
navsat_transform:
  ros__parameters:
    frequency: 30.0
    delay: 4.0 # Seconds to wait before calculating the transform from GPS coordinates to your robot’s world frame.

    zero_altitude: false
    yaw_offset: 0.0

    broadcast_utm_transform: false
    publish_filtered_gps: false

    wait_for_datum: true
    datum: [59.6099, 16.5448, 0.0] #  latitude, longitude, heading (in radians)
    # Note: A heading of 0 is toward the east, positive is counter-clockwise.


ekf_filter_node_map:
  ros__parameters:
    frequency: 30.0
    two_d_mode: false
    print_diagnostics: true
    debug: true
    publish_tf: true
    use_control: false

    map_frame: map
    odom_frame: odom # r3live publishes the odometry in the "world" frame instead of the "odom" frame

    world_frame: map

    base_link_frame: aft_mapped # r3live publishes the odometry of the "aft_mapped" frame on the topic "/aft_mapped_to_init"

    # Directly use roll, pitch and yaw 
    odom0: aft_mapped_to_init
    odom0_config: [false, false, false,
                  true,  true, true,
                  false, false, false,
                  false, false, false,
                  false, false, false]
    odom0_queue_size: 10
    odom0_differential: false
    odom0_relative: false

    # Differentiate X, Y and Z  to get linear velocities and avoid conflicts with the GNSS fix.
    odom1: aft_mapped_to_init
    odom1_config: [true, true, true,
                  false, false, false,
                  false, false, false,
                  false, false, false,
                  false, false, false]
    odom1_queue_size: 10
    odom1_differential: true
    odom1_relative: false

    # Fully use the GNSS fix
    odom2: odometry/gps
    odom2_config: [true,  true,  true,
                  false, false, false,
                  false, false, false,
                  false, false, false,
                  false, false, false]
    odom2_queue_size: 10
    odom2_differential: false
    odom2_relative: false

    process_noise_covariance: [1.0,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    1.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    1e-3,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01,   0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.5,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.5,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.1,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.3,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.3,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3]

Observed topic messages
ros2 topic echo /aft_mapped_to_init
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1726739722
    nanosec: 790758797
  frame_id: odom
child_frame_id: aft_mapped
pose:
  pose:
    position:
      x: 0.10258937213147493
      y: 2.7701529127127364
      z: 0.024107572558434473
    orientation:
      x: -8.282671855659729e-06
      y: -0.009924303899904296
      z: 0.6448299265475481
      w: 0.7642616528075862
  covariance:...
twist:
  twist:
    linear:
      x: 0.044240643416767325
      y: 0.6249538835056032
      z: 0.08919482097844317
    angular:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance:...

ros2 topic echo /odometry/global
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1726739822
    nanosec: 348192361
  frame_id: map
child_frame_id: aft_mapped
pose:
  pose:
    position:
      x: -0.25974070818647876
      y: 0.19798858059338026
      z: -1.7405198023880515
    orientation:
      x: -0.03348903951968671
      y: -0.08314526315978304
      z: -0.9451438254890524
      w: 0.31411542239447443
  covariance:...
twist:
  twist:
    linear:
      x: 0.1696467914398178
      y: 0.014912242395973692
      z: 0.048012318595715454
    angular:
      x: -0.01823663157281553
      y: 0.008895651118444689
      z: 0.7269163760872626
  covariance:...

ros2 topic echo /tf
transforms:
- header:
    stamp:
      sec: 1726663091
      nanosec: 867570688
    frame_id: odom
  child_frame_id: aft_mapped
  transform:
    translation:
      x: -0.6022346466302645
      y: -0.4813953435053505
      z: 0.04574495798068348
    rotation:
      x: 0.00692517750300668
      y: -0.004017908657183388
      z: 0.29452136667764633
      w: 0.9556113555713461
---
transforms:
- header:
    stamp:
      sec: 1726740012
      nanosec: 400888082
    frame_id: map
  child_frame_id: odom
  transform:
    translation:
      x: -0.08354226009412274
      y: 0.43476403067130615
      z: -0.037945088323984674
    rotation:
      x: 0.004705087695066744
      y: -0.003720210643958476
      z: 0.4770191784565508
      w: 0.8788724171159222


I experienced issues while using the robot_localization package and got an answer, so I wanted to share it here.
Summary: I was using the navsat_transform_node with data coming both from a ros2_bag file and a running node.
The navsat_transform_node gave an error message saying it was missing a "map" -> "aft_mapped" transform, even though this transform was correctly published.
In fact, the solution for me was to make sure both transforms were published with coherent timestamps, because the time stamps of the two transforms were different by about a day, which apparently cannot be handled by tf.
